# Should we merge questions about deep frying oil?

Tags: discussion

I have a, not so good, question about deep frying oil, that has an excellent answer. There are two other questions about oil maintenance that also have nice answers. Should these questions be merged to create one authoritative Q&A?

Links:

- [My question - with lettuce](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24028/can-you-extend-the-life-of-frying-oil-with-lettuce)
- [Keep deep frying oil](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6419/how-to-keep-my-deep-frying-oil-usable-as-long-as-possible)
- [Frying oil reuse](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/frying-oil-reuse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I think it's ok and doesn't need to be merged. [Why duplicates aren't always a problem](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) was covered in the blog by Jeff a couple of years ago, and I think this case meets all those criteria.

In addition, I think your question has something important about it. While two questions may have the same answer, that doesn't mean they should be merged. The issue is that it's not necessarily obvious that the second question will be answered by the first so it becomes harder to discover. If someone hears the same piece of folk lore about lettuce and wants to find an answer, they won't necessarily read (or even find) the general frying oil reuse question. However, when they see your question, they'll think, 'Jackpot!' which is exactly the point.

Comment: Cool! I'd forgotten about Jeff's blog.